# Sequelize: How to define a field as a function?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have defined the following model:

```
const Project = sequelize.define('project', {
  version: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    field: Sequelize.fn('concat', Sequelize.col('version_major'), '.', Sequelize.col('version_minor'))
  }
});
```

Then I'm trying to execute a `findAll` with following params:

```
myProjectModel.findAll({
  where: { version: '2.0' },
  attributes: ['version']
});
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
SequelizeDatabaseError: Unknown column '[object Object]' in 'where clause`
```

However, if I remove the where clause, the attribute works fine. Sequelize is translating the field correctly in the select clause but incorrectly in the where clause:

```
SELECT concat(`version_major`, '.', `version_minor`) AS `version` FROM `project` WHERE `project`.`[object Object]` IN ('2.0');
```

Any ideas? `getterMethods` doesn't work for `findAll` method.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is `setter` method before inserting :

```
const Project = sequelize.define('project', {
  version: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    set(val){
        let version_major = this.setDataValue('version_major');
        let version_minor = this.setDataValue('version_minor');
        return version_major+'.'+version_minor;
    }
  }
});
```